# .htaccess redirect based on refferer with masking original base URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a url http://a.bc.com which is pointed to the ip address `xx.xx.x.xx` which will open up http://www.example.com

Now I want to show some particular page like http://www.example.com/somedirectory/somepage/ if some one hits http://a.bc.com

But I want keep my original URL same followed by directory and page. Ex, http://a.bc.com/somedirectory/somepage/
I tried this .htaccess which is not working for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://a\.bc\.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/somedirectory/somepage/ [R=301,L]
```

Please help me with the .htaccess with masking original base URL

Comment: This will not work. You can't manipulate the domain part of the URL with `.htaccess`. (Except the redirect you do atm.)

Comment: This would need _proxy_ functionality.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_HOST doesn't include PROTOCOL, so remove protocol part from RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.bc\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* /somedirectory/somepage/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: your suggestion gave me error: This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: You redirect to http://www.example.com/somedirectory/somepage/ or to http://a.bc.com/somedirectory/somepage/?